# jquery select from within element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

How do I do this (but in a way that works):

```
$("MyElem").get("[id$='Date']").datepicker();
```

Essentially I'm trying to select all elements that end with the word "Date" in the id within the context of a given parent element.

So this should be interpreted as:

1. Get "MyElem".
2. From "MyElem" search all children recursively and find id's that end with "Date".
3. For each item in the results of step 2 call datepicker on that element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not using `find` method:

```
$('#myelem').find('[id&=Date]').datepicker();
```

Or why not using a better selector:

```
$('#myelem *[id$=Date]').datepicker();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`find` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/find/):

```
$(elementReference).find("[id$='Date']").datepicker();
```

where `elementReference` is either a DOM element or a selector. If it already is a jQuery object, then just do `elementReference.find(...`.